# On click, animate button

Tags: javascript, performance

i am trying to animate my buttons when a user clicks on them using the following code

```
                <script language="javascript">

        $(function() {
            $("#b01").focusin(function() {
                animate(".btnn", 'bounce');
                return false;
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            $("#b02").focusin(function() {
                animate(".bl02", 'bounce');
                return false;
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            $("#b03").focusin(function() {
                animate(".bl03", 'bounce');
                $("#b03").focusout();
                return false;
            });
        });

        function animate(element_ID, animation) {
            $(element_ID).addClass(animation);
            var wait = window.setTimeout( function(){
                $(element_ID).removeClass(animation)}, 1300
            );
        }
    </script>
```

i want a better way of writing my code so that if the buttons increase, i dont have to add a specific function for that button only. Thanks

Comment: what's the logic? do you have some map? each case looks different in the example.

Comment: Who upvoted this... why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $("#b02").focusin(function() {
                animate(".bl02", 'bounce');
                return false;
            });
```

should be:

```
  $(".btn").focusin(function() {
                animate(this, 'bounce');
                return false;
            });
```

then assign a class 'btn' to all your buttons.

and don't do this all over the place:

```
$(function() {

     /// ... put your code in here
});
```

it should only happens **once**.. and put all the btn code in there..

Comment: I have one suggestion for the above answer -Do not use "class 'btn'" use "Id" because if you have 4 buttons in the UI with different shape , size and color then you will be having different classes for them so attach same ids to all the buttons .